# Localize Facebook and Twitter Share Panels on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

My app uses different languages, within the app the language can be changed and I have share button in my app which shares the images in Facebook and twitter. By default it appears in English. After changing the language in my app to french, The content in Facebook (i.e) Post and cancel button should be changed to french. Is it possible and how to do it?

Comment: u need the localization change only social media integration , try this link http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have control over the language of the share panels because iOS handles that for you, automatically localizing them based on the setting that the user picked in the iOS settings app. Your application probably shouldn't have a localization option in it unless there's a very good reason for it, but in any event, you can't localize the share panel.